# Android: how to place two elements at the center of a layout so that one overlaps the other

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout that must stretch to cover the whole with of the screen. Inside I need to place two images, both placed at the center of the layout in such way that the second image - which happens to be smaller - overlaps the second image.

Basically it should look like two concentric circles.

Using a linear layout I can center one of the images with no problem. But since I need to add the second overlapping image I have switched to Relative layout and I am not obtaining the desired results:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#ff0000">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#ffff00">
        
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/MyImageAtBackground"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/bigCircle" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/MyImageAtForeground"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/smallCircle" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Notice that with the previous xml the "bigCircle" image is indeed centered, but the second one -"smallCircle"- remains at the left top corner of "bigCircle".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this easily with ConstraintLayout. The smaller image will be centered according to the larger, if you want to move the larger and still have the smaller centered. [Produces this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaCfX.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/MyImageAtBackground"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/MyImageAtForeground"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#00FF00"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/MyImageAtBackground"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/MyImageAtBackground"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/MyImageAtBackground"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/MyImageAtBackground" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```